# Как избавиться от FFFFFFFF в конце вывода?

Tags: java

Стоит задача:

"Для каждого байта, считанного из `System.in`, в `System.out` должно быть выведено шестнадцатеричное представление этого байта. Например, для байта `13` должны быть выведены символы `"0D"`, для байта `127` — символы `"7F"`, для байта `-128` — символы "`80`".

Для любого байта должно быть выведено ровно два символа; при необходимости добавляется ведущий нуль. Шестнадцатеричные цифры должны выводиться в верхнем регистре."

Мой код постоянно добавляет `0A` в конце - как я понимаю это символ перевода строки или еще что? Я от него избавляюсь в условном операторе, но система выдает такой ответ:

```
Your output:
48656C6C6F20576F726C6421FFFFFFFF
Correct output:
48656C6C6F20576F726C6421
```

Не могу понять в чем дело?

Спасибо!

Вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int newByte = 0;
        while(newByte != -1){
            newByte = System.in.read();
            String res = Integer.toHexString(newByte).toUpperCase();
            if (!res.equals("A")) {
                if (res.length() == 1) res = "0" + res;
                System.out.print(res);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, скоро крайний срок сдачи наступает, не могу разобраться в чем причина

Comment: Вам нужно сначала ввести значение, а потом его проверять на `-1`. А вы делаете наоборот. (И выучите отладчик, без него никуда.)

Comment: `-1` в шестнадцатеричном виде это `FFFFFFFF` (для `int`)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while(newByte != -1){
>   newByte = System.in.read();
> ```

Ты сначала проверяешь, а потом читаешь. Надо так:

```
 while((newByte = System.in.read()) != -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read` возвращает `char`, а не `int`.

Если приходит код `0A` то нужно просто перестать писать в поток. Сделайте блок  в виде `bool`.

Да и собственно кто пишет в поток `in`?

Comment: вот этот блок и есть bool? 

if (!res.equals("A")) {
                if (res.length() == 1) res = "0" + res;
                System.out.print(res);
            }

у меня все правильно выводит. я не понимаю откуда в превеяющей системе берутся FFFFFF

Comment: Кто пишет в поток?

Comment: И у Вас не bool а проверка, если не 0A то писать. А нужно сделать примерно так:  if (res.equals("A")) notwrite = true; if(!notwrite) пишем..

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал ваш код, и честно говоря не совсем понимаю почему, но если вы уберете проверку на !res.equals("A") это вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этом месте

```
        newByte = System.in.read();
        String res = Integer.toHexString(newByte).toUpperCase();
```

надо проверять `newbyte`.

Например:

```
        newByte = System.in.read();
        if (newByte == -1)
          break;
        ...
```

Ну, и соответственно, под такое изменение кода можете подправить условие в `while (...)` (надеюсь, очевидно как).